# Debug Alfresco 4.2 Web scripts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is there a way to debug Alfresco Web Scripts at runtime ? I am talking about webscripts server side. In particular I am developing an AMP for Alfresco 4.2 which make use of a WS in the classic form: .xml + .js + .ftl, therefore not a Java Backed Web Scripts.

The .js controller is developed as part of the AMP, and is placed in the relevant directory for being uploaded at AMP developing/run time.

I would like to put breakpoints in .js controller to use all facilities provided by the Eclipse debug perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this thing in eclipse below blow will help you in that case.
Details are on middle of blog.

http://axel-faust.de/?cat=3&lang=en

There is also debugger available in alfresco and share ,in webscript servuce page.

You will also find option for same in below url.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index

Click Refresh Web Scripts on the Web Scripts Home page to ensure the Web Script Framework has cleared its caches.
Click List Web Scripts.
Click Alfresco JavaScript Debugger.
Click Enable to launch the JavaScript Debugger in a separate window.

Comment: Good find. I knew about Alfresco debugger, but I completely missed the post you are mentioning. Give me few time to test before marking as accepted. Did you use it ? If yes have you found any particular issues ?

Comment: no haven't used it but it seems to be use full.I founded it a year ago and saved it.

Comment: also worse to mention: Javascript Console is a very helpful tool for testing on production systems without the need to run expensive debug.